# How to get row index in Dropdownlist selectedIndexChanged?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using a gridview and sqldatasource.

I have a dropdownlist in my gridview with 2 values : Yes and No .

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    DropDownList ddl = ((DropDownList)row.FindControl("DropdownList1"));
    if(ddl.selectedvalue == "1")
        //etc..
}
```

I need to get the Row index because this `GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];` is not available in the current event.

Comment: Just a UI issue, if you only have two values you should use a radioButtonList. A DropDownList would require two clicks, where a RadioButtonList requires only one.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As @mellamokb has already mentioned, you always get the control that raised an event by the sender argument, you only have to cast it accordingly.

```
DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)sender;
```

If you also need to get a reference to the `GridViewRow` of the `DropDownList`(or any other control in a TemplateField of a GridView), you can use the [`NamingContainer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.namingcontainer.aspx) property.

```
GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)ddl.NamingContainer;
```

> but I need to get the row index for getting a value from a templatefield who's not a dropdown is a textbox

You can get any control once you have the  `GridViewRow` reference by using `row.FindControl("ID")` (TemplateField) or `row.Cells[index].Controls[0]` (BoundField).

For example (assuming there's a `TextBox` in another column):

```
TextBox txtName = (TextBox)row.FindControl("TxtName");
```

Comment: Thank you , ok but I need to get the row index for getting a value from a templatefield who's not a dropdown is a textbox.

Answer (score 4):

If all you are looking for is the value of the dropdownlist, that's passed in as the `sender`:

```
DropDownList ddl = sender as DropDownList;
if (ddl.SelectedValue == "1")
   // do something...
```

Comment: done it worked , but do you know how can I get the row ? because I need to get in the same event the value of a templatefield : for example this is in row updating event :   String DS = ((TextBox)row.Cells[6].FindControl("TXT")).Text;

Comment: I think you can do `ddl.Parent`, or it might be `ddl.Parent.Parent`.  You'll have to experiment how many levels in the hierarchy you have to go out to find the GridViewRow.

Comment: I'm not intending to get the dropdown row , I just need the row edit index for getting a value from a templatefield .

Comment: They're the same thing.  Getting the "row edit index" so you can say `MyGrid.Rows[ix].Cells[...]` is the same as getting "the dropdown row".  Once you have a reference to the `GridViewRow` container, you can say `row.Cells[6].FindControl("...")` or even just `row.FindControl("...")` to get access to that other control in the same row.

Comment: I wasn't able to get it : string s = s =  GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[3].FindControl("TextBox3").ToString(); I object reference not set to an instance of object but the cell num is the right one same with the control name

Comment: I don't think we're on the same page.  Try @TimSchmelter's suggestion and see if that works.

Answer (score 1):

```
Protected Sub ddlneedlocationcmf_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim gvrow As GridViewRow = CType(sender, DropDownList).NamingContainer
    Dim rowindex As Integer = CType(gvrow, GridViewRow).RowIndex


End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer! While a code snippet could answer the question it's still great to add some addition information around, like explain, etc ..